# Duplicate Rows in Google Spreadsheet based on a single cell Value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, information-hiding

I'm trying to programmatically duplicate rows in a Google spreadsheet. I would like the number of times the row is duplicated to be based on one single cell value.

For example:

the cell L10 contains the value 45
The row 23 is containing different values (value list, formulas, vlookup etc) and I would like to repeat this row embarking all formulas 44 times just above the first one so 45 rows from the row 23 til row 67.

I tried the code mentioned in the request with very similar question but was not able to adapt to my needs.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCEBq.png)

Comment: and to be more precise, i would like to know the script and a button is waiting to be assigned:) thnanks a lot

Comment: why voting -1??

Comment: Hey again @MzoSchöwenier, please make sure to select the proper tags next time ;)

Comment: ok sorry! and thanks a lot i will test it!!

Answer (score 0):

I have created a sample sheet on my side that looks like this:

[image: my sample sheet]

I then created the following script:

```
function insertXRows() {
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var count = sheets.getRange(3,6).getValue(); //F3
  Logger.log(count);

  //Get my to be copied line
  var copyLine = sheets.getRange(9,2,1,7); //Fix these values depending on your row that you want to copy.
  while(count>0) {
    Logger.log(count);
    //Get last line of my data
    var lastRow = sheets.getDataRange().getValues().length;

    var newRow = sheets.getRange(lastRow+1, 2, 1, 7); //Fix these values depending on your row that you want to copy.
    for (var i = 0; i<copyLine.getValues()[0].length; i++) {
      if (copyLine.getFormulas()[0][i]!="") { //Check formulas first
        sheets.getRange(newRow.getRow(), newRow.getColumn()+i).setFormula(copyLine.getFormulas()[0][i]);
      } else if (copyLine.getValues()[0][i]!="") {
        sheets.getRange(newRow.getRow(), newRow.getColumn()+i).setValue(copyLine.getValues()[0][i]);
      }
    }
    count--;
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Zektor ans thanks a lot for you support. I've tried it but I see that first the process takes time. Secondly, I can't embark formulas (some of cells have choice list, some of them contain formulas etc) But finally. I think that I can do the contrary = If I prepare a doc with for instance 100 similar rows, maybe I can have a script deleting the last row til I get the right number. For instance, the row is duplicated from the row 23 to 122, but I only need 45 rows, so I would expected the script to delete row 68 >122. maybe it's easier that way and takes not so long? what do you think? Thanks

Comment: Hello. You can use the getDataValidations() methods the same way the getFormulas() method is used.